# Is there anyway to delay an embedded segue in a container view?

Tags: iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, location, segue

I am currently working on an app in Swift that has a list of locations in a tableview that is embedded inside another view controller. The issue I am having is that it loads the segue before I get the users location. I need it to wait until the location has been acquired. This is what I am currently doing:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if let embeddedVC = segue.destinationViewController as? MapList where segue.identifier == "locationList" {

        embeddedVC.longitude = self.longitude
        embeddedVC.latitude = self.latitude

    }


}
```

Current it just passes a location of 0,0 because there is not time for it to update before doing the segue.

Comment: take a look at the `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` function - you can return false there, then wait for the location and *then* trigger the segue again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by using this code:

```
var embedvc:MapList?
```

Then in the prepareForSegue function:

```
if (segue.identifier == "locationList") {

    let detailScene = segue.destinationViewController as! MapList

    self.embedvc = detailScene;

}
```

and then when I want to pass the location:

```
self.embedvc?.latitude = self.latitude
self.embedvc?.longitude = self.longitude
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Property Observers** like `didSet` and `willSet` to monitor the longitude and latitude changes. Once both changed preform the segue.

For example:

```
var tup : (longitude: Int, latitude: Int) = (0,0) {
didSet {
  print("Segue")
  //Segue here
  }
}

tup = (longitude: 1, latitude: 2)
```

Once `tup` is changed, you can trigger the segue

Comment: I am using a container view and it is trigger automatically when "viewDidLoad" runs. Is there a way to make a container view without it auto running?

Comment: @Idan with an embedded segue there is no trigger.